# Unable to cache ajax data on document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, caching

I am using following code to fetch and cache data from a ASP.NET handler. The problem is that whenever I cache data using a button click its working fine, but I want this to happen at `document.ready()` event. When I executed this code on `document.ready()` event, its fetching data perfectly, but its not getting data from the cache when I reload the page.

```
var localCache = {
            data: {},
            remove: function (url) {
                delete localCache.data[url];
            },
            exist: function (url) {
                return localCache.data.hasOwnProperty(url) && localCache.data[url] !== null;
            },
            get: function (url) {
                console.log('Getting in cache for url' + url);
                return localCache.data[url];
            },
            set: function (url, cachedData, callback) {
                cacheTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                localCache.remove(url);
                localCache.data[url] = cachedData;
                if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback(cachedData);
            }
        };
        var now;
        var cacheTime;
        var tDiff;
        function getValueAtIndex(index) {
            var str = window.location.href;
            return str.split("/")[index];
        }
        //$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Button1').click(function (e) {
            var url = '/Handlers/ResponseFetcher.ashx';
            var topicid = "<%=desid %>";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data:
                    JSON.stringify({ tid: topicid })
                ,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    now = (new Date()).getTime();
                    if (localCache.exist(url)) {
                        tDiff = now - cacheTime;
                        if (tDiff < 20000) {
                            loadData(localCache.get(url));
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    localCache.set(url, jqXHR, loadData);
                }
            });

        });

        function loadData(data) {
            console.log("now: " + now + ", cacheTime: " + cacheTime + ", tDiff:" + (cacheTime - now));
            $('#responseloader').hide();
            var resdata = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
            $(resdata).each(function (i) {
                $('#responsecontainer').append("<div>" + this.Title + "</div>");
            });
        }
```

Here `tDiff` will be `undefined` on first run. Is this the problem? or caching doesn't work if the page is reloaded? Please help!

Comment: What makes you think that localCache is persisted over page loads?

Comment: so how should I solve this?

Comment: If you want to persist data on the client, then you might want to use localStorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @76484 what about those browser that doesn't support HTML5?

Comment: Cookies. Or a server-side solution - maybe you have to populate your localCache.data object on the server.